# ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 2) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

getting this issue whilst trying to process cifar data.
heres the code

```
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y,stratify=y)

Xtrain = Xtrain/255.0
Xtrain = Xtrain.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 3)

Xtrain_flat = Xtrain.reshape(-1, 3072)

Xtest = Xtest/255.0
Xtest = Xtest.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 3)

Xtest_flat = Xtest.reshape(-1, 3072)

pca = PCA(0.9)
pca.fit(Xtrain_flat)

PCA(copy = True, iterated_power = 'auto',
    n_components = 0.9, random_state = None,
    svd_solver='auto', tol = 0.0, whiten = False)

pca.n_components_

train_pca = pca.transform(Xtrain_flat)
test_pca = pca.transform(Xtest_flat)

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop



ytrain = np_utils.to_categorical(ytrain)
ytest = np_utils.to_categorical(ytest)

batchSize = 128
numClasses = 10
epochs = 20

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (pca.n_components_,)))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(numClasses, activation = 'softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_pca, ytrain, 
                    batch_size = batchSize, 
                    epochs = epochs,
                    verbose = 1,
                    validation_data =(test_pca, ytest))
```

I know its some sort of issue within the resizing of the sets, but I cannot figure out where the issue is and how to fix it myself. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is the shape of train_pca?

Comment: Expected target length is 10 according to the last layer of your model. What is the shape of `ytrain/ytest`? Is it [nrows, 10]?

Comment: The shape of train_pca is 7500, 96, and y train and test are 7500, 10, 2 and 2500, 10, 2 respectively